# How to package assets with a node module

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I'm trying to include some simulation data with a node module (module B) and then be able to reference that data from the calling module (module A). The data is a text file in the `/data` directory of module B. I have a function on module B that calls up the data using __dirname, but of course when this function is called from module A, the __dirname references the directory of module A... not module B.
What's the best way to include asset data like this and make it available in the consuming module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When packaging a module you can use the [`files` property of package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) to bundle any assets along with your module.

Then, in that module, you can use a *relative* path to reference your included asset.

Imagine a module with this file structure:

```
 -assets
   |-data.txt
 index.js
```

In your *package.json* you might have a `files` section that looked like:

```
files: [
    'index.js',
    'assets/data.txt'
]
```

And in *index.js* you could expose your asset data like so:

```
let fs = import 'fs';

function getAssetData() {
   return fs.readFileSync('./assets/data.txt')
}

module.exports = { getAssetData };
```

Comment: Thanks, @duncanhall. I'll give that a shot. Sounds like the right way to do it.

Comment: It works only within that package; but if you use this package in other projects, it will fail to find that `./asset/data.txt` file.

Should use `__dirname` or its ES6 equivalent...