# How to Handle Assets in NodeJS Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a NodeJS module that is supposed to translate an XML to HTML via an XSL file. The problem is I need to bundle the XSL with the rest of the module.

Right now it's inside the source folder and I use it via:

```js
function createHtml(xml) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const xsltProcessor = require('xslt-processor');

    var xsl = fs.readFileSync('./src/xsl/html-export.xsl', 'utf-8');
    return xsltProcessor.xsltProcess(xsltProcessor.xmlParse(xml), xsltProcessor.xmlParse(xsl));
}
```

Of course I made sure to have this folder in the `files` property of the *package.json*:

```
    "files": [
        "src"
    ],
```

This setup works inside the module, but not when I publish the module and require it from a second module. Then I need to copy the XSL file into the second module's path as well.

That's not really working for me. I want to access the file relative to the JavaScript source file, not the current NodeJS application.

I tried using a different kind of path (*html-export.xsl*, *./html-export.xsl*, *./xsl/html-export.xsl*) but nothing else works even inside the module. So I can't publish it to try it out elsewhere.

The good news is: the XSL file is actually included inside the module during the publishing; when I install it the module in the *node_modules/* folder contains the XSL. So it's "just" the above code that's not working, because the path is resolved relative to the second module (i.e. the one with the `require`), not relative to the original one (i.e. the one inside the *node_modules/*).

How do I handle assets in NodeJS so they are bundled with the module they belong to?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982425/how-to-package-assets-with-a-node-module) seems related, but the answer is exactly what I did, and it doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're 'including' the "files" correctly.. While it's kind of difficult to see what you're doing (maybe supply the structure of the files/modules you're using would help), you can try to do something like this: `"files": [ "src/*" ],`

Comment: @MattOestreich The file in question **is** in the _node_modules/_ folder of the second module, so it is definitively included.

Comment: Then what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @MattOestreich I can't access the file via the above code, because the path is resolved relative to the second module, not relative to the original one (in the _node_modules/_ folder).

Comment: Is this package on GitHub? What does the structure look like? You should just have to expose the file via your `index.js` or however you're exposing your API. Alternatively, you could do something like `const xsl = require('YourPackage/path/to/html-export.xsl')`.. In the link you supplied, they are exposing the function which imports that file - are you doing something like that or no?

Comment: @MattOestreich Since SO (at least some of the tags I frequent) has a bullying problem I'm not comfortable sharing personal data (like a GitHub account) here. And I don't even really need to expose the XSL file. I just need it internally to transform that XML. Which should be transparent to the user, he just puts an XML file into the module and gets HTML out from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you only want to use the `.xsl` file internally in your package, which is something that I originally misunderstood..

In order to accomplish this, you can use the `path` package to resolve the path of your `.xsl` file.

***Like this:***

```
function createHtml(xml) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const xsltProcessor = require('xslt-processor');

    var xsl = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './src/xsl/html-export.xsl'), 'utf-8');
    return xsltProcessor.xsltProcess(xsltProcessor.xmlParse(xml), xsltProcessor.xmlParse(xsl));
}
```

In order to demonstrate how to do this, I have built an example NPM package for you to review. While this package doesn't use an `.xsl` file, it uses a `.txt` file - the logic remains the same.

The readme file within the package contains instructions on how to use it..

[You can find the package on NPM here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/so-require-file-example)

[You can find the source code to the package here](https://github.com/oze4/so-require-file-example)